# How to draw a custom icon with a changeable backgroundcolor?

Tags: ios

Im trying to rebuild the exact same thing as shown in the image.

[image]

Depending on the location of your finger the background color of the pin should change accordingly to the image colors. But that's not the point. I am just searching for a way to create this pin with a changeable background color.

I have tried to use a png with transparency inside and outside as a mask for a `UIView` but that way I am only getting the border without any fill.

[image]

Comment: Did you try template rendering mode? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778682/ios-using-default-color-on-image-rendered-as-template

Comment: I think that would just do the same effect that the inner is still transparent.

Comment: No. I've used this a lot. Use a template image, preferably in pdf format, .png, and you set the color that you want. If you need a border and a background, you might have to use two images, one for the background and one for the border, though trying to use the view.layer properties for border and borderColor is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Using a UIImage with rendering as a Template image is a pretty simple way to achieve this.

Here is a demo project where you can drop your pin image (make sure it is 30x30 pts) to make sure it works.

https://github.com/joelesli/TemplateImageDemo/tree/master

[image]

To change the border and the background you can either

1. Use a separate image for the border
2. Try and use the
   imageView.layer.border and .borderColor attributes (haven't tried
   it)

Answer (score 0):

Might not be a perfect solution but you could create a custom `PinView` class like this:

```
@IBDesignable
class PinView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = .black {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = .black {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let px = rect.midX
        let py = rect.maxY - borderWidth

        let cx = rect.width / 2
        let cy = rect.width / 2

        let radius = rect.width / 2 - (borderWidth / 2)

        let dx = cx - px;
        let dy = cy - py;

        let dd = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        let a = asin(radius / dd)
        let b = atan2(dy, dx)

        var t = b - a
        let ta = CGPoint(x: radius * sin(t),
                         y: radius * -cos(t))

        t = b + a
        let tb = CGPoint(x: radius * -sin(t),
                         y: radius * cos(t))

        // create path
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: px, y: py))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cx + ta.x, y: cy + ta.y))

        let startAngle = atan2((cy + ta.y) - cy, (cx + ta.x) - cx)
        let endAngle = atan2((cy + tb.y) - cy, (cx + tb.x) - cx)

        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: cx, y: cy),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: startAngle,
                    endAngle: endAngle,
                    clockwise: true)

        path.close()

        // prepare drawing colors / settings
        fillColor.setFill()
        borderColor.setStroke()

        path.lineWidth = borderWidth

        // draw
        path.fill()
        path.stroke()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sharedInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedInit()
    }

    private func sharedInit() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        isOpaque = false
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        sharedInit()
    }

}
```

Then you can simply update the `fillColor`, `borderColor` and `borderWidth` depending on your needs.